# Find the word 'x++' in Fulltextsearch SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, stop-words

I'm trying to indexing the word 'x++' in my fully indexed field, but I don't know how. I think the problem is that the '+' char is not included in indexing list chars.

Executing the query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(DB_ID('my_db'), OBJECT_ID('my_table'))
```

I noticed that the work 'c++' is indexed, so I think there should be a way to ask my sqlserver to index specific word ('c++' is very similar to 'x++' ).

Thanks everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for something like this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE '%x++%'
```

Comment: Thanks @Danieboy, but because of the dimension of the data I cannot use the LIKE operator. I've to fully index the column an using the query     select * FROM table_name where  CONTAINS(column_name,'"x++"')